# How do I compare two values within a block using ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models in my app, User and Result. Result belongs to User. In order to create a Result record I have to validate if the user exist.

If the user exists, I want to create the result record in the respective user account.  Otherwise, I want to create e new user and then create the Result record who belongs to him.

The Result data comes from an XML document and there's an email node which I can use as an identifier to create the records.

The solution I thought was compare the email attribute in the User table against the Result email node from the XML.

How can I build a block to compare User.email with Result.email?

e.g:

```
if user.email == result.email
  # create record on table result
else
  # create user and create record on table result
end
```

Comment: you want to compare the values between which records?

Comment: Lets say User has 100 records, Result has 200 records.. 20 of them have common email.. what do you want nw and with which records.. ?

Comment: You question isn't clear. You seem to be trying to get an attribute out of a collection of records, which is not possible. Anyway, is this what you're looking for? `User.all.pluck(:email).uniq`?

Comment: Or maybe what you're trying to say is there is an association between the two models and you're looping through each record while comparing two associated records?

Comment: This will be better done using custom SQL. Not very efficient in ruby.

Comment: Thanks Depa, yes they are. I will edit the the question and try to explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Result.all.each do |result|
  user = User.where(:email => result.email).first_or_create
  result.update_column(:user_id => user.id)
end
```